# How to get current route within resolve function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a service which checks whether the current user has access to the route.
I would like that service to be called as part of the resolve, so that the view never loads if the user should not have access. However, within the resolve function the $state dependency does not yet contain the actual state of the router.

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: 'app/home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController',
  controllerAs: 'main',
  resolve: {
    allowed: function(auth, $state) {
      return auth.isAllowed($state.current.name);
    }
  },
})
```

... however `$state.current.name` is empty at the point which it is used. How can I pass the state's name (i.e. "home")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
resolve: {
   allowed: function(auth) {
      return auth.isAllowed(this.self.name);
   }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

For UI router 1.0+: inject $state$ to get access to future state (to which transition is in progress). However, if resolve is in parent or abstract state, it will point to that abstract state, not child state to which transition is.

```
resolve: {
    allowed: function($state$) {
    ...
    }
}
```